# How to let function end when another one starts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have many canvases and two functions: one for mouseover on each of them and one for mouseout on each of them.
The first one increases the square and the second one decreases.

```
    area.addEventListener("mouseover", function animate() {
        //increasing
    });

    area.addEventListener("mouseout", function animate() {
        //decreasing
    });
```

The problem is, when one of squares increases and the other one also starts increasing(when the first one still works), the first one stops.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading...functions end almost immediately - but an **animate** function will probably set up various timing callbacks to continue running more functions as time progresses. Chances are if it's a commonly-used animation library, it will provide a mechanism to cancel midway.

Comment: who told you he's using any animation library? It looks like those are just normal JavaScript listeners there and he named the function that way. Still, very hard to say what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand: So you want to be able to hover an area and have both squares scale out if need be? 

Side note: I don't know if you meant it this way, but having three gajillion canvases is probably making the problem more difficult than it needs to be, why not just use a single canvas properly?

Comment: my suggestion: if you reinvent the wheel, you'll often get stuck in it. Use jQuery animate function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which provides a .complete callback function and a .queue option.

Comment: I'm not using animation libraries. Pytth, yes, I meant it. What do you mean by "use a single canvas properly". I need a map of independent squares.

Comment: Confusing question: in title you want the first function to stop, in details you want both animations to run in parallel. You should make up your mind. Also provide some code where you do the animation bit.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/meJUgm1J